# Create AWS QuickSight resources with AWS CLI command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to create a script that will provision QuickSight account and will configure the following parameters:

- Subscription type
- SPICE Capacity
- VPC connection
- QuickSight access to AWS services

From the [AWS CLI QuickSight documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/index.html) I couldn't find a way to create the account, choose subscription type and change SPICE Capacity.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the 'register user' command from the CLI.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/register-user.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Eric E I couldn't register a user without creating account first through console.